# Remove document with references Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having trouble removing Question when Survey gets deleted which is referenced in the Survey model. The survey gets deleted, but the question still remains in the database.

Survey Schema:

```js
let surveyModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    Title: String,
    Type: [String],
    Questions: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "questions" },
    Answered: { type: Number, default: 0 }, // how many times users answered
    DateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, // date created
    Lifetime: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, // Survey expiry
    User: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "users" }
  },
  {
    collection: "surveys",
  }
);
```

Question Schema:

```js
let questionModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    MC: {
      QuestionText: String,
      Options: [String],
    },
    TF: {
      QuestionText: String,
      Options: Boolean,
    }
  },
  {
    collection: "questions",
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Question", questionModel);
```

Code I have right now:

```js
// process survey delete
module.exports.processDeletion = (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  
  Survey.remove({ _id: id }, (err) => {
    Question.remove({_id: { $in: req.body.Questions }}, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.end(err);
      }
    });
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end(err);
    } else {
      // refresh survey list
      res.redirect("/live-surveys");
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be delete childrens, that is Question.

**Note**: i think "Questions" should be more of 1, then it must be an array of Reference in the Survey model. But, for this example it will to be as you have setted.

Then, your delete route, may to be some as:

```
router.delete("/delete/:surveyById", deleteSurvey");
router.param("surveyById", surveyId"); //This one is your middleware
```

```
//surveyController.js

const Survey = require("../models/Survey");
const Question = require("../models/Question");

exports.surveyId = (req, res, next, id) => {
  Survey.findById(id).exec((err, data) => {
    if(!data || err) return res.status(400).json({error: "Survey not found")};
    else {
      req.survey = data;
      next();
    }
  )};
};

exports.deleteSurvey = (req, res) => {
  Questions.findByIdAndRemove(req.survey.Questions) //Here your Questions Id
  .exec((err, data)) => {
    if(err) return res.status(400).json({error: "Error to delete questions"});
    Survey.findByIdAndRemove(req.survey._id).exec((err, data) => {
      if(err) return res.status(400).json({error: "Error to delete Survey"});
    return res.json({ message: "Deleted")};
    });
  });
};
```

Also you can do with async await if you prefer, is the same, and you will have a better control about your code.